# Area of polar region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the area of the region which lies inside the circle $r = 1$ but outside the parabola $r = \dfrac{1}{1+cos\theta}$.

**Attempt:**

I determined that the area of the region can be expressed as the double integral

$$\int _{\frac{-\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _{\frac{1}{1+\cos\theta}}^{1}rdrd\theta$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2} \int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta + 2\cos\theta + 1})d\theta$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2} \int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos^2\theta + 2\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta + 2\cos\theta + 1}d\theta$$

Where does one go from here? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can always try the $\theta  = 2\tan^{-1} t$ substitution

Comment: Yes, and the integral turns out very easy.

Comment: @Lavar Ball Did you solve this after their hint? Are you still interested in seeing a solution?